# window with Shadow around it in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

[image: This image is from w3school]

How to create the window (kind of thing) with shadow around it in web page.
Thanks

Comment: When I google "css shadow" I receive 11.7 million results. None of these work for you? [_"How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?"_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use box shadow

```css
.container {
  background-color: #d9d7d7;
  padding: 1em;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px #5f5f5f;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!-- Insert content inside here -->
  <p>
    Test content
  </p>
</div>
```

Also, extra advice, if you ever have a webpage that contains html/css that you want to imitate, use inspect element. You can see the html and css structure so you can see exactly how its done!

Answer (score 1):

```css
.box{
 height: 100px;
 width: 300px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <h3 class="box-title">Customer Details</h3>
</div>
```

For Making Custom Shadow You Can Visit **[Here](https://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow)**

Or Learn box-shadow at **[here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp)**